# terminate read with either of two delimiters (ie. read -d '.' -> read -d '[Ee]')

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing on a shell script where users should enter a string (followed by enter), and there are some characters that terminate the 'read' command immediately. I did research and found this:

```
read -d '.'
```

So this means that the read command will be terminated when '.' is entered. So I can type

```
Hello, this is the user's input.
```

And when the dot is entered, 'read' will terminate.

But I need this with different delimiters. I need a way to get 'read' to terminate when e.g. 'E' OR 'e' is entered by the user.
I tried it with wildcard:

```
read -d [E,e]
```

but then, '[' is the terminating delimiter. 'read' ignores 'E' and 'e', but terminates when '[' is entered.

I also tried several "-d" flags:

```
read -d 'E' -d 'e'
```

But it seems like the second '-d' overwrites the first. Just 'e' is token as terminating delimiter, 'E' is ignored.

What can I do? Is there any other possibility with 'read', or maybe another command?

Comment: The argument to `-d` very specifically supports a single character; if you pass in multiple, it will only use the first of those.  What are you *actually* hoping to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, -d takes the first character of the argument as terminating delimeter, but in my case, there should be different characters that termiante 'read'.

Comment: I understand your question but what sort of user experience requires this sort of behavior? Why do you want input to work in this way? Are you sure it's not an unpleasant surprise for most users?

Comment: So that read is terminated when "E" OR "e" is entered.

Comment: Yes, nothing about what you want is unclear, but it's still not clear why you want this, or how it's not a design bug rather than a feature.  Look for "raw mode" input tools.

Comment: Well, the trouble is that the user should answer some questions, and there are just some character, the script accepts as last character. So in my case, these are the characters 'E' and 'e'. The script askes and the user should answer with a string whose last character is either 'E' or 'e'. The number of characters is given: 2. So the User should enter two characters, and the second should be either 'E' or 'e'.

Comment: See there, a new requirement which lets you solve this easily: `read -n 2`

Comment: See also [XY Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: Instead of trying to impose multiple conditions on the `read`, why not simply let the user enter whatever they will and you read the entire line and then test/parse what they have entered to determine whether or not the input in valid? You do this in a loop and you can enforce whatever input policy you like without trying to torment `read` into doing something it wasn't meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
string=''
store_IFS="$IFS"                # Storing current IFS value
IFS=                            # Setting IFS to Null to space characters to enter
while true              
do
    read -sn 1 k                 # -n for reading byte by byte  and -s is to suppress the printing of input.

    if [ "$k" = $'\177' ] && [ -n "$string" ]    # Check whether it is backspace and string is not empty
    then
        printf %b "\b \b"         # '\b' moves the cursor 1 unit left and then printing '\b' then again moves the cursor left so that it looks like a character erased :)
        string=${string::-1}     # Now remove the last character from the string
        continue
    fi

    # Now check for each delimiter you want.
    case $k in
    [Ee])
        break   
        ;;  
    esac

    # Now Concatenate that byte with the previous input string
    string+=$k
    printf '%s' "$k"  # Now print the current inputted char
done
IFS="$store_IFS"        # Restoring IFS value
printf '\n%s\n' "Your string -> $string"
```

I don't know if there is an inbuilt commands for doing that, but you can easily implement it with the above bash code.

**Edit**

Fixed mistakes in the code as suggested in the comments

Comment: What do you meant by incorrect characters, can you please be more specific?

Comment: I just mean, when the user entered text and he wants to correct it :-)

Comment: I changed the code to handle backspace, it solve your problem. Have any questions?

Comment: `[ $k == 'E' ]` is going to be buggy in lots of cases. The user enters a space, you get `[ == E ]`. The user enters a `*`, you get `[ file1 file2 file3 == E ]`; etc. Better to use `[[ $k == E ]]` or `[ "$k" = E ]`, with either the quotes or the use of `[[ ]]` suppressing string-splitting and glob expansion... or just `[[ $k = [Ee] ]]`, or, even better, `case $k in [Ee]) ...;; esac`, which works in all POSIX-compliant shells.

Comment: (BTW, the use of `=` rather than `==` in the suggested code above was not a typo; `==` is an extension, whereas POSIX test only guarantees `=` to be available as a string-comparison operator; using the single-character form is thus a better habit to be in if one may need to write scripts compatible with baseline-POSIX systems).

Comment: ...same issues exist around `echo $k`; it should always be `echo "$k"`. And `printf '%s' "$k"` is more reliable than `echo -n "$k"`; the latter can print `-n` on stdout, even in bash, if `set -o posix; shopt -s xpg_echo` has been run (or compile-time flags or environment variables establish equivalent defaults are active). See also the APPLICATION USAGE of the POSIX standard for `echo` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html

Comment: (Similarly, `print %b "\b \b"` is a POSIX-compliant alternative to `echo -ne "\b \b"`)

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy for pointing out my mistakes, and I edited my answer. I think there is a typo `print` (actually shlould be `printf` I think) in the last comment. Let me know if there are any mistakes

Comment: Much better, yes. (And my apologies about the typo). BTW, any reason you're setting `IFS=` repeatedly, rather than before the loop starts?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a kludgey function that reads in one char at time, and if it's not a terminator passed in the first argument, prints each char to *STDERR* (for user feedback) and *STDOUT* (to assign to a variable):

```
readdelim() { n=["$1"']{1}'
              while read -s -N 1 v ; do 
                  [[ "$v" =~ $n ]] && break
                  printf "$v" | tee /dev/stderr
              done
              echo > /dev/stderr; }
```

Use it like so:

```
n=$(readdelim eE) ; echo $n
```

...and type something like *"ba bat bate"*, and the contents of `$n` will be *"ba bat bat"*.

Comment: I'm still puzzling over how to pass `readdelim` a linefeed, so that it'll quit if the user presses the *Enter* key...

Comment: How does this cope with backspace?

Comment: @tripleee, I dunno... consider `n=$(readdelim eE) ; echo "${n@A}"`, which, if we type *"a<backspace>e"* outputs `n=$'a\177'`.  OTOH, I'm not sure how to `echo` the `$n` so the output backs up over the *"a"*.